# React throwing SyntaxError - Use of const in strict mode in Chrome 34

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack

I have a react app using webpack that works fine in an updated Chrome browser but throws an error in Chrome 34.  We have a client that needs to use Chrome 34 so we have to support it.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

The error is happening in the webpack bundle file in the project.  Here is the line in the bundle.js file that is throwing the error.

```
"use strict";
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(__resourceQuery) {\n\n/* global __resourceQuery WorkerGlobalScope self */\n/* eslint prefer-destructuring: off */\n\nconst url = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/url/url.js\");\nconst stripAnsi = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js\");\nconst log = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js\").getLogger('webpack-dev-server');\nconst socket = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js\");\nconst overlay = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js\");\n\nfunction getCurrentScriptSource() {\n  // `document.currentScript` is the most accurate way to find the current script,\n  // but is not supported in all browsers.\n  if (document.currentScript) { return document.currentScript.getAttribute('src'); }\n  // Fall back to getting all scripts in the document.\n  const scriptElements = document.scripts || [];\n  const currentScript = scriptElements[scriptElements.length - 1];\n  if (currentScript) { return currentScript.getAttribute('src'); }\n  // Fail as there was no script to use.\n  throw new Error('[WDS] Failed to get current script source.');\n}\n\nlet urlParts;\nlet hotReload = true;\nif (typeof window !== 'undefined') {\n  const qs = window.location.search.toLowerCase();\n  hotReload = qs.indexOf('hotreload=false') === -1;\n}\nif (true) {\n  // If this bundle is inlined, use the resource query to get the correct url.\n  urlParts = url.parse(__resourceQuery.substr(1));\n} else {\n  // Else, get the url from the <script> this file was called with.\n  let scriptHost = getCurrentScriptSource();\n  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape\n  scriptHost = scriptHost.replace(/\\/[^\\/]+$/, '');\n  urlParts = url.parse((scriptHost || '/'), false, true);\n}\n\nif (!urlParts.port || urlParts.port === '0') {\n  urlParts.port = self.location.port;\n}\n\nlet hot = false;\nlet initial = true;\nlet currentHash = '';\nlet useWarningOverlay = false;\nlet useErrorOverlay = false;\nlet useProgress = false;\n\nconst INFO = 'info';\nconst WARNING = 'warning';\nconst ERROR = 'error';\nconst NONE = 'none';\n\n// Set the default log level\nlog.setDefaultLevel(INFO);\n\n// Send messages to the outside, so plugins can consume it.\nfunction sendMsg(type, data) {\n  if (\n    typeof self !== 'undefined' &&\n  (typeof WorkerGlobalScope === 'undefined' ||\n  !(self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope))\n  ) {\n    self.postMessage({\n      type: 'webpack' + type,\n      data: data\n    }, '*');\n  }\n}\n\nconst onSocketMsg = {\n  hot: function msgHot() {\n    hot = true;\n    log.info('[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.');\n  },\n  invalid: function msgInvalid() {\n    log.info('[WDS] App updated. Recompiling...');\n    // fixes #1042. overlay doesn't clear if errors are fixed but warnings remain.\n    if (useWarningOverlay || useErrorOverlay) overlay.clear();\n    sendMsg('Invalid');\n  },\n  hash: function msgHash(hash) {\n    currentHash = hash;\n  },\n  'still-ok': function stillOk() {\n    log.info('[WDS] Nothing changed.');\n    if (useWarningOverlay || useErrorOverlay) overlay.clear();\n    sendMsg('StillOk');\n  },\n  'log-level': function logLevel(level) {\n    const hotCtx = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/webpack/hot ^\\\\.\\\\/log$\");\n    const contextKeys = hotCtx.keys();\n    if (contextKeys.length && contextKeys['./log']) {\n      hotCtx('./log').setLogLevel(level);\n    }\n    switch (level) {\n      case INFO:\n      case ERROR:\n        log.setLevel(level);\n        break;\n      case WARNING:\n        // loglevel's warning name is different from webpack's\n        log.setLevel('warn');\n        break;\n      case NONE:\n        log.disableAll();\n        break;\n      default:\n        log.error('[WDS] Unknown clientLogLevel \\'' + level + '\\'');\n    }\n  },\n  overlay: function msgOverlay(value) {\n    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {\n      if (typeof (value) === 'boolean') {\n        useWarningOverlay = false;\n        useErrorOverlay = value;\n      } else if (value) {\n        useWarningOverlay = value.warnings;\n        useErrorOverlay = value.errors;\n      }\n    }\n  },\n  progress: function msgProgress(progress) {\n    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {\n      useProgress = progress;\n    }\n  },\n  'progress-update': function progressUpdate(data) {\n    if (useProgress) log.info('[WDS] ' + data.percent + '% - ' + data.msg + '.');\n  },\n  ok: function msgOk() {\n    sendMsg('Ok');\n    if (useWarningOverlay || useErrorOverlay) overlay.clear();\n    if (initial) return initial = false; // eslint-disable-line no-return-assign\n    reloadApp();\n  },\n  'content-changed': function contentChanged() {\n    log.info('[WDS] Content base changed. Reloading...');\n    self.location.reload();\n  },\n  warnings: function msgWarnings(warnings) {\n    log.warn('[WDS] Warnings while compiling.');\n    const strippedWarnings = warnings.map(function map(warning) { return stripAnsi(warning); });\n    sendMsg('Warnings', strippedWarnings);\n    for (let i = 0; i < strippedWarnings.length; i++) { log.warn(strippedWarnings[i]); }\n    if (useWarningOverlay) overlay.showMessage(warnings);\n\n    if (initial) return initial = false; // eslint-disable-line no-return-assign\n    reloadApp();\n  },\n  errors: function msgErrors(errors) {\n    log.error('[WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.');\n    const strippedErrors = errors.map(function map(error) { return stripAnsi(error); });\n    sendMsg('Errors', strippedErrors);\n    for (let i = 0; i < strippedErrors.length; i++) { log.error(strippedErrors[i]); }\n    if (useErrorOverlay) overlay.showMessage(errors);\n  },\n  error: function msgError(error) {\n    log.error(error);\n  },\n  close: function msgClose() {\n    log.error('[WDS] Disconnected!');\n    sendMsg('Close');\n  }\n};\n\nlet hostname = urlParts.hostname;\nlet protocol = urlParts.protocol;\n\n\n// check ipv4 and ipv6 `all hostname`\nif (hostname === '0.0.0.0' || hostname === '::') {\n  // why do we need this check?\n  // hostname n/a for file protocol (example, when using electron, ionic)\n  // see: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/pull/384\n  // eslint-disable-next-line no-bitwise\n  if (self.location.hostname && !!~self.location.protocol.indexOf('http')) {\n    hostname = self.location.hostname;\n  }\n}\n\n// `hostname` can be empty when the script path is relative. In that case, specifying\n// a protocol would result in an invalid URL.\n// When https is used in the app, secure websockets are always necessary\n// because the browser doesn't accept non-secure websockets.\nif (hostname && (self.location.protocol === 'https:' || urlParts.hostname === '0.0.0.0')) {\n  protocol = self.location.protocol;\n}\n\nconst socketUrl = url.format({\n  protocol: protocol,\n  auth: urlParts.auth,\n  hostname: hostname,\n  port: urlParts.port,\n  pathname: urlParts.path == null || urlParts.path === '/' ? '/sockjs-node' : urlParts.path\n});\n\nsocket(socketUrl, onSocketMsg);\n\nlet isUnloading = false;\nself.addEventListener('beforeunload', function beforeUnload() {\n  isUnloading = true;\n});\n\nfunction reloadApp() {\n  if (isUnloading || !hotReload) {\n    return;\n  }\n  if (hot) {\n    log.info('[WDS] App hot update...');\n    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require\n    const hotEmitter = __webpack_require__(\"./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js\");\n    hotEmitter.emit('webpackHotUpdate', currentHash);\n    if (typeof self !== 'undefined' && self.window) {\n      // broadcast update to window\n      self.postMessage('webpackHotUpdate' + currentHash, '*');\n    }\n  } else {\n    log.info('[WDS] App updated. Reloading...');\n    self.location.reload();\n  }\n}\n\n/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, \"?http://localhost:8080\"))\n\n//////////////////\n// WEBPACK FOOTER\n// (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080\n// module id = ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http:/localhost:8080\n// module chunks = 0 1\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///(webpack)-dev-server/client?");
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ava",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "broadwayjs": "0.0.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.2.2",
    "react-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "react16-spinjs": "^3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch --hot",
    "build": "webpack -d --watch --hot",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what could cause this only in Chrome 34?

Comment: The same issue crops up in very old versions of Node.js. IIRC, what's happening is that the engine started to enforce the reserved word policy but not actually support its use as a declarator. If you need to support that environment you need to transpile the code, I suggest TypeScript or Babel

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Babel env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) to target the browser you are looking for.

Change your babel config to something like this (not tested):

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "Chrome >= 34"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have it narrowed down to an issue with the webpack version.  If I use the latest version it works in Chrome 34.  The problem is that we were using an earlier version to get around an error we were having with one of our modules.  Looks like it is time to deal with that issue.